# Finding a door in an infinitly long wall

Tags: complexity-theory

Let's say you stand in front of a massive wall.
The wall is infinitly long to your right and left side. You know that there is a door somewhere and you try to find it to reach the other side. 
Sadly, it is night and you can only feel the part of the wall in front of you.

You don't know how far away the door is or what direction you have to go but you can count your steps, starting from your startpoint.

How can you solve this problem?

The naive approach would be to start at the startpoint and go +1 to the right, check and if no door is found, go to the start and go -1 and check again. If there is still no door you would have to go to the start and check +2 to the right and so on....

This would result in O(n^2) steps to find the door (Where n is the number of steps from the startpoint to the door).

Is there a better way? Maybe even in O(n) steps?

I don't even exactly know what tags I should ask this so feel free to add some if you think they fit.

Comment: Why would you go -1 towards left. Keep going right till the door is not found or its the end of wall. If it was the end of wall travel backwards i.e towards left, If there's a door you will find it. The time complexity of this walk is O(2*N) which is order **`O(N)`**

Comment: @ishpreet The Wall is infinitly long in both directions

Comment: you would start at 0, check and if no door is found you look at -1 and 1. If no door is found you look at -2 and 2, etc. Would that not be O(n^2) ?

Comment: n is the distance from point 0 (start) to the door. So since you check both sides equally you reach the door after n^2 steps

Comment: Instead of going at each step again use this +1,-1,+2,-2,+4,-4,+8,-8 ... This will reduce your N*N complexity

Comment: @ishpreet in that case, when at position 1 you would need 2 steps to go from 1 to -1. 4 steps to Go from 2 to -2 and so on

Comment: You are skipping half iteration again Like you won't visit 3 or 5,6,7 separately. You will visit them only in their successors like 4 or 8 respectively. And if there was a door at 6 or 7 you will stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you don't know which way to go, so whatever solution you come up with, you have to go back to the origin and start going the other way. Furthermore you can never rule out either of the directions until after you've found the door making you go back to origin any number of times with any algorithm with sufficiently large `n` (where I assume n is the distance of the door from the origin).

That means we want to go back as little as possible, but we still will have to. The solution is to not increment the step by just one, but travel twice the distance.

For simplicity without hurting the asymptotic complexity, we will travel distance d to some point, then come back, travel the same distance to the other direction and finally come back again. This only gives us constant `4` for our complexity, so we can disregard it later. Anyways when I will talk about an iteration, it means all of these 4 routes even though you will have found the door before completing all of them in the last iteration.

So in the first step you can travel to tile 2, in second to tile 4, then 8, 16, etc.

You will find the door in the k-th iteration where `2^k >= n > 2^(k-1)`, which means `k >= log(n) > k-1`. For simplicity we can assume that n is a power of 2, because for the computation it doesn't matter if n is for example 33 or 64 (or minus any of those), we will find all of these in the same iteration. So we can write `k = log(n)`.

You are now summing just part of geometric sequence, so after k-th iteration you will have traveled total of `4 * 2*(2^k - 1)/(2 - 1) = 8 * (2^log(n) - 1) = 8 * (n - 1) = 8n - 8 = O(n)`.